# Java.exe does not open with Process.start

Tags: java, c#, command-line, process

I have an application that needs to be opened with Java.exe . when i try to open the application with Command prompt with the following arguments

C:\MyworkingFolder\>start java -MyParamters ->This works and the application is launched

But when i use the same in my c# code

```
var pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "Java",
                WorkingDirectory = "MyworkingFolder",
                Arguments = -MyParamters 
            };

            Process monitorProcess = Process.Start(pInfo);
```

This code part does not work. All that i get is a window that shows OpenWith

Comment: shouldn't it be the full path to java.exe?

Comment: @Farhan No.. the java path will be taken from the Envoronment variables its in C:ProgramFiles\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\JavaPath

Comment: Have you tried specifying `java.exe` with extension?

Comment: The application now works fine.. I have given the full path for Java "C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe" and it works now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The application now works fine.. I have given the full path for Java "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" and it works now.